# dbnary SPARQL query yield zero results, how to find the cause?

Tags: sparql, wiktionary, dbnary

I have some basic experience in using SPARQL with Wikidata, and now I'm trying my first steps in [DBnary](http://kaiko.getalp.org/about-dbnary/), an attempt to extract structural RDF data from Wiktionary.

The first [example](http://kaiko.getalp.org/about-dbnary/online-access/) they give loads all available German translations of the English word *cat*, which [works great](http://kaiko.getalp.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=&query=SELECT%20DISTINCT%20%3Ft%2C%20%3Ff%2C%20%3Fo%20WHERE%20%7B%0D%0A%20%3Ft%20dbnary%3AisTranslationOf%20dbnary-eng%3Acat__Noun__1%20%3B%20%0D%0A%20dbnary%3AtargetLanguage%20lexvo%3Adeu%20%3B%0D%0A%20dbnary%3AwrittenForm%20%3Ff%20.%0D%0A%20OPTIONAL%20%7B%3Ft%20dbnary%3Agloss%20%3Fo%7D%0D%0A%7D&format=text%2Fhtml&timeout=0&debug=on):

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?t, ?f, ?o WHERE {
  ?t dbnary:isTranslationOf dbnary-eng:cat__Noun__1 ; 
  dbnary:targetLanguage lexvo:deu ;
  dbnary:writtenForm ?f .
  OPTIONAL {?t dbnary:gloss ?o}
}
```

Now I tried the same to get all English translations of the Italian word *voglia* (the meanings of *voglia* are available both in the [English](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/voglia) and the [Italian Wiktionary](https://it.wiktionary.org/wiki/voglia)). But the following SPARQL [does not yield any results](http://kaiko.getalp.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=&query=SELECT%20DISTINCT%20%3Ft%2C%20%3Ff%2C%20%3Fo%20WHERE%20%7B%0D%0A%20%3Ft%20dbnary%3AisTranslationOf%20dbnary-ita%3Avoglia__Noun__1%20%3B%20%0D%0A%20dbnary%3AtargetLanguage%20lexvo%3Aeng%20%3B%0D%0A%20dbnary%3AwrittenForm%20%3Ff%20.%0D%0A%20OPTIONAL%20%7B%3Ft%20dbnary%3Agloss%20%3Fo%7D%0D%0A%7D&format=text%2Fhtml&timeout=0&debug=on):

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?t, ?f, ?o WHERE {
  ?t dbnary:isTranslationOf dbnary-ita:voglia__Noun__1 ; 
  dbnary:targetLanguage lexvo:eng ;
  dbnary:writtenForm ?f .
  OPTIONAL {?t dbnary:gloss ?o}
}
```

I'm getting zero results with many other words too.

How can I find out where the problem lies? Is it my query, or is it the data? How can I check whether the word *voglia* is present in DBnary at all?

Comment: Try [`DESCRIBE dbnary-ita:voglia__sost__1`](http://kaiko.getalp.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=&qtxt=describe+dbnary-ita%3Avoglia__sost__1+%0D%0A%0D%0A&format=text%2Fx-html%2Btr&timeout=0&debug=on) or check http://kaiko.getalp.org/dbnary/ita/voglia__sost__1. *Sost* is for *sostantivo*.

Comment: `SELECT DISTINCT * WHERE {
 ?t dbnary:isTranslationOf ?s
filter(strstarts(str(?s),str(dbnary-ita:)) && contains(str(?s),"voglia"))
}` to find URLs with the term. The URL itself is http://kaiko.getalp.org/dbnary/ita/voglia - open it in the browser to see all data available about it